# Recursively count all sub-arrays in a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have the following PHP array:

```
Array
(

    [13] => Array
        (
            [bond] => 5
            [level] => 1
            [sub] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [bond] => 7
                            [level] => 2
                            [sub] => Array
                                (
                                    [7] => Array
                                        (
                                            [bond] => 9
                                            [level] => 3
                                            [sub] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [18] => Array
                                        (
                                            [bond] => 6
                                            [level] => 3
                                            [sub] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [24] => Array
                                        (
                                            [bond] => 9
                                            [level] => 3
                                            [sub] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [bond] => 4
            [level] => 1
            [sub] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [bond] => 5
            [level] => 1
            [sub] => Array
                (
                    [19] => Array
                        (
                            [bond] => 8
                            [level] => 2
                            [sub] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

How can I count, for each entry, the count of its sub entries, if any?

So to these keys/values should be **added** to the array:

```
[13]['count'] = 1;
[13][1]['count'] = 3;
[13][1][7]['count'] = 0;
...
[14]['count'] = 0;
... etc
```

I can't wrap my head around this. Is it a recursive function? Is it a while(true) loop inside a foreach loop? Do I use global variables to alter the array?

I tried everything I could come up with and I just can't do it.

EDIT:

Here's my solution for 2 levels deep. I am unable to make this recursively work for infinite levels:

```
   foreach($items as $cell=>$data){
      $count = count($data['sub']);
      $items[$cell]['count'] = $count;
      if ($count){
         foreach($data['sub'] as $cell2=>$data2){
            $count = count($data2['sub']);
            $items[$cell]['sub'][$cell2]['count'] = $count;
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Yes, you can probably do this by all the methods you mentioned (although I'd probably go for a recursive function). Can you post your most promising attempts in the question?

Comment: this array looks like a tree, search for 'Tree Traversing Algorithms'

Answer (score 2):

- your code is o.k, but the sentence **Here's my solution for 2 levels deep. I am unable to make this recursively work for infinite levels** is not o.k at all. In **recursion** you never process children nodes/other nodes in the current node, you can't process level 2 in level 1, the idea is to break the problem into sub problems and treat each independently as if it was standing there all alone.
- Basically, in such a problem like yours (where the output of each level is some thing accumulated to the output of the previous level), you will need to make a function that accepts the output of the previous level as a parameter, accumulate your output in each level and then redoing it again for children

```html
function processTree(&$parent, $items) {
   // here treat this node/level as if it were alone, there are no children
   foreach($items as $cell=>$data){
      $count = count($data['sub']);
      // so you just need to accumulate the current count to the parent array
      $parent[$cell]['count'] = $count;
      if ($count){
         // and here you process children passing them their parent array to which they will accumulate their output     
  processTree($parent[$cell], $data['sub']);
      }
   }
}
// start the output with an empty array for level 1 nodels
$res = array();
processTree($res, $your_tree);
print_r($res);
```

I hope that the idea of recursion isclear, the most important thing is not getting the job done but knowing how it's done, so I'm here if you have comments

Comment: Oh dear God you freaking saved me. Sorry for my words, but I was DESPERATELY trying to figure out how to recursively count subarray sizes to find out the largest one no matter where in the array it would be, with your code I've managed it. THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad that something this old helped you :D